# SwiftUI NavigationLink doesn't trigger with onReceive method

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm trying to learn how to do basic login in swift with Firebase and it's causing me to lose my mind over navigating to the main page of the app once the login is complete. I have a `ViewModel` that manages the login, and in the view I have added an `onReceive` property to listen on a viewModel's boolean to detect sign in and trigger the navigation. I don't understand why it's not working, any help would be greatly appreciated!

ViewModel:

```
class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    var userInfo: User?
    
    @Published var isSignedIn = false
    
    func signIn(email: String, password: String) {
        auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { _, error in
            if let error = error as? NSError {
                print("Error happened on login"+error.description)
            } else {
                print("Login successful")
                if let user = self.auth.currentUser {
                    print("We have a user")
                    self.userInfo = user
                    self.isSignedIn.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

View:

```
struct LoginPage: View {
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = LoginViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Email", text: $email).padding()
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                        .padding()
                    TextField("Password", text: $password).padding()
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                        .padding()
                    Button(action: {
                        guard !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty else {
                            return
                        }
                        viewModel.signIn(email: email, password: password)

                    }, label: {
                        Text("Sign in")
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 12, leading: 35, bottom: 12, trailing: 35))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                    })
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Login")
        }.onReceive(viewModel.$isSignedIn) { isSignedIn in
            if isSignedIn {
                print("ok damm")
                NavigationLink(destination: HomePage()) {
                    EmptyView()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note that "ok damm" prints every time.

Comment: You can't put SwiftUI `View`s in the middle of imperative code like you've done with that `NavigationLink`. The `NavigationLink` has to go in the view hierarchy itself. If you search for "SwiftUI programatic navigation" you'll find a number of resources.

Comment: @jnpdx I see, and how can I trigger the navigation automatically then? Especially since `NavigationLink(destination, isActive, label)` is deprecated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer by Jatin Bhuva works but is deprecated for iOS 16. Here's the solution for new iOS versions:

```
struct LoginPage: View {
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = LoginViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Email", text: $email).padding()
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                        .padding()
                    TextField("Password", text: $password).padding()
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                        .padding()
                    Button(action: {
                        guard !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty else {
                            return
                        }
                        viewModel.signIn(email: email, password: password)

                    }, label: {
                        Text("Sign in")
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 12, leading: 35, bottom: 12, trailing: 35))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                    })
                    Text("Don't have an account yet ?").padding(EdgeInsets(top: 20, leading: 0, bottom: 10, trailing: 0))
                    Button(action: {
                        guard !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty else {
                            return
                        }
                        viewModel.signUp(email: email, password: password)
                    }, label: {
                        Text("Create an account")
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 12, leading: 35, bottom: 12, trailing: 35))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                    })
                }
            }.navigationTitle("Login")
                .navigationDestination(isPresented: $viewModel.isSignedIn) {
                    HomePage()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Notice how I replaced the `NavigationView` with a `NavigationStack` and added `.navigationDestination(isPresented:)` that listens for changes on my model's `isSignedIn` published property.

Comment: Just in case it works for your surrounding needs, I wanted to suggest simply using an if/else statement over isSignedIn, rendering your Sing In content when false, and HomePage() when true. At least when scoped to what you've provided in your question, there isn't really a need to deal with NavigationLink for this. Also, you probably want to replace '@ObservedObject' with '@StateObject' or else LoginPage's view lifecycle could re-initialize ViewModel unexpectedly.

Comment: @AlexFringes thanks for the feedback, will look into it. My goal with that example is to learn how to lay the first bricks towards building a full-fledged app, with clean code, MVVM and all. If I just wanted to log in with firebase I probably would have done what your suggested without bothering with a separate ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code it will help you to solve your issue:

```
NavigationLink(destination: Text("Second View"), isActive: $isSignedIn){
                EmptyView()
            }
```

View:

```
struct LoginPage: View {
    @State var email = ""
    @State var password = ""

    @ObservedObject var viewModel = LoginViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            ZStack {
                VStack {
                    TextField("Email", text: $email).padding()
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                        .padding()
                    TextField("Password", text: $password).padding()
                        .background(Color(.secondarySystemBackground))
                        .padding()
                    Button(action: {
                        guard !email.isEmpty, !password.isEmpty else {
                            return
                        }
                        viewModel.signIn(email: email, password: password)

                    }, label: {
                        Text("Sign in")
                            .padding(EdgeInsets(top: 12, leading: 35, bottom: 12, trailing: 35))
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                            .background(Color.blue)
                            .cornerRadius(15)
                    })
                }

              NavigationLink(destination: HomePage()), isActive: $isSignedIn){
                EmptyView()
            }
            }.navigationTitle("Login")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey ! So, it seems to be working but "isActive" is deprecated as of iOS 16. Any workaround ?

Comment: No idea for that.

Comment: I got, will be posting answer asap

Answer (score 0):

switch statement in swiftui can handle that easily. I use it all the time;

```
//Added code
enum LoginStages {
    case preLogin, postLogin
}

class LoginViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let auth = Auth.auth()
    var userInfo: User?
    @Published var loginStage: LoginStages = LoginStages.preLogin 
//Added code

    @Published var isSignedIn = false

func signIn(email: String, password: String) {
    auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { _, error in
        if let error = error as? NSError {
            print("Error happened on login"+error.description)
        } else {
            print("Login successful")
            if let user = self.auth.currentUser {
                print("We have a user")
                self.userInfo = user
                self.isSignedIn.toggle()
                loginStage = .postLogin //Added code
              }
           }
        }
     }
  }
```

And your view should look like this;

```
struct LoginPage: View {
  @State var email = ""
  @State var password = ""

  @ObservedObject var viewModel = LoginViewModel()

  var body: some View {
   switch viewModel.loginStage {
   case .preLogin:
   //This is ur initial code which the user sees before login.
   // the same as the code you have above.
  case .postLogin:
  //Here, just call the post login view after a successful login;
  // I am assuming it is called home view for this example.
  HomeView()
 
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That does work for this case in particular, but for a multi-page application I'd still endup running into that issue, say if I wanna open the settings page. Having a global app state a giant switch/case on the root view seems like a weird way to solve that issue when NavigationLink exists.

Comment: Hi @Tom, for the issue you raised, this will solve it as agreed, and I believe that switch statement is cleaner than using more than one if else. Think about it?